# Plugin pagination?

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

So i've got a plugin which adds a shortcode to WordPress. When applied, it pulls data from a remote API, parses it, and displays it accordingly. The API internally paginates the data in the form of query arguments 'per_page' and 'page' where 'per_page' is how many items to display per page, and 'page' is which page in the set to display. What I'm having issues with is figuring out the best way to handle this type of pagination on the frontend. The only option I've come up with so far is pulling the total number of pages, displaying a pagination bar accordingly, and passing whatever number (or next/prev) as POST variables back to the function that's displaying the data. This solution seems hackish at best, and would require excess page reloads that I'd rather not have. Does anyone have any suggestions as to a cleaner way of handling this? Ideally, I'd like it to load the data inline, i.e.; not reload the page at all.

Here's what I'm currently using...

```
<?php if ($result->info['pages'] > '1') {
    if ($result->info['page'] != '1') {
        echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . ($result->info['page'] - 1) . '\');">Prev</a> ';
    } else {
        echo 'Prev ';
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $result->info['pages']; $i++) {
        if ($i == $result->info['page']) {
            echo $i . ' ';
        } else {
            echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . $i .'\');">' . $i . '</a> ';
        }
    }
    if ($result->info['page'] != $result->info['pages']) {
        echo '<a onClick="location.replace(\'?page=' . ++$result->info['page'] . '\');">Next</a>';
    } else {
        echo 'Next';
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the question correctly -

but why not use the [wordpress "built-in"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) pagination functions ?

or - you can also try using the offset parameter at the query.

You might also want to look [HERE](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin) - this pagination function can get a parameter of custom loops.

**Edit I** (after comments suggested the question is not about query but about ajax)

This is a very simple example, you would have to change it a bit to make it work for you depending on page structure.

```
<div id=”content”>
<div id=”post-list”>
            (Post Loop Here)
</div>
</div>
<div id=”ajaxPagination”>Load more</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var pageNumber = 1;
var baseURL = $(location).attr(‘href’);

$(‘#ajaxPagination’).click(function() {
$(‘#ajaxPagination’).html(‘Loading…’);
pageNumber++;
var link = baseURL + ‘page/’ + pageNumber + ‘/’;
$.ajax({
url: link,
success: function(html) {
var result = $(html).filter(‘#content’);
$(‘#post-list’).append(result);
$(‘#ajaxPagination’).html(‘Load more’);
},
error: function(html) {
$(‘#ajaxPagination’).html(‘No more..’);
}
});
});

})
```

Alternatively, there are many plugins that do just that , and a handfull f tutorials on the web which you can dissect the code and see how it is done (or just use the plugin as - is )

Examples : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-pagination/installation/

http://www.99points.info/2011/01/ajax-pagination-using-jquery-and-php-with-animation/

etc ..

Comment: the built-in pagination isn't exactly what I need. I'm currently using something that does incorporate the query page and total pages parameters... Problem is that I want to load the new data without reloading the page and thus far I'm falling far short of being able to accomplish this.

Comment: without reloading the page ? you would need ajax for that .. that is not a query or object problem..

Comment: I've figured that part out... I just can't figure out ajax.

Comment: Ok - so it is strange that in your question the word "ajax" does not appear , nor did you mentioned that you want it without reloading . Now that your question is better understood - I will get back to you .

Comment: My apologies, after rereading the initial question I can understand your confusion. Thank you for your help thus far. I can't use the actual pagination plugin, as this is intended to be included in another plugin (a widget and shortcode that both require pagination). I'll take a look through the code posted as well as your examples though.

Comment: I posted the plugin also because even if you can not use it directly (and you could) - you can read it´s code and see how it works. believe me - reading code is the fastest track to learn.

Comment: I'm getting frustrated to the point that I'm about ready to pay someone to do it for me, or at least walk me through making it do what I need it to. For some reason while PHP comes easily, ajax I just can't get. :(

Comment: did you tried to search here, on this same website, for "wordpress ajax pagination" ? - there are some good questions that can help you with that .

Comment: yes, pretty much all of them seem to suggest using a third party plugin... exactly what i don't want to do.